# extract variable names using BCEL library

Tags: java, bcel

hi i am using bcel library to read byte code. I needed to extract the variables names.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Note that method-local variable names don't exist at the level of the class file: at the btyecode level, they're just referred to by local variable number. So if you're looking for these, you won't find them...

Comment: Java includes these names by default but obfuscators may change them, it links to a class string.